# Index out of range: Mapping the output of a 3-input function to a 3-dimentional floating-point array in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception, indexoutofrangeexception

I want to set the elements in a mutable 3d array of Doubles to the output of a 3-input function, `f()`, for the position of that element in the array (`[a][n][b]`), then print the array.

```
//3-input function must input and output doubles. This function is an example.
func f(a: Double, n: Double, b: Double) -> Double {
    return a * n * b
}

//Size of array: 7*7*7
let aMax = 6
let nMax = 6
let bMax = 6

//Define mutable array; I don't know if I need to initialize array "points".
var points = [[[Double]]]()

//I don't know if I should use ".append" or "=".
for a in 0...aMax {
    for n in 0...nMax {
        for b in 0...bMax {
            points[a][n][b] = f(a: Double(a), n: Double(n), b: Double(b)) //Changing element at position results in "fatal error: Index out of range".
        }
    }
}

print(points)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after doing:

```
var points = [[[Double]]]()
```

`points` is completely empty. So any attempt to access any of the indexes results in the "Index out of range" error.

Since you are going to fill the whole thing, initializing the three dimensions using `Array(repeating:count:)`.

```
var points = Array(repeating: Array(repeating: Array(repeating: 0.0, count: bMax + 1), count: nMax + 1), count: aMax + 1)
```

Now the rest of your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this , for an array declared like this `[[[Double]]]` you can use append only but for assigning and indexing it you must first init it like this

```
//Size of array: 7*7*7
let aMax = 7
let nMax = 7
let bMax = 7

//Define mutable array; I don't know if I need to initialize array "points".
var points = [[[Double]]](repeating: [[Double]](repeating: [Double](repeating: 0, count: bMax), count: nMax), count: aMax)

//I don't know if I should use ".append" or "=".
for a in 0..<aMax {

    for n in 0..<nMax {

        for b in 0..<bMax {
            points[a][n][b] = (f(a: Double(a), n: Double(n), b: Double(b))) //Changing element at position results in "fatal error: Index out of range".
        }

    }

}

print(points)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare and initialize a "3D" array in a single shot, using `Array.map(_:)`:

```
let (aCount, nCount, bCount) = (8, 8, 8)

let points: [[[Double]]] = (0 ..< aCount).map { aInt in
    let a = Double(aInt)

    return (0 ..< nCount).map { nInt in
        let n = Double(nInt)

        return (0 ..< bCount).map { bInt in
            return f(a: a, n: n, b: Double(bInt))
        }
    }
}
```